# How to pass value to httpget ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The Url bellow i am passing and wanted to receive value from my httpget ActionResult method. I already tested and getting error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. Any idea to correct url or whats the solution?

> http://localhost:53081/Dashboard/UpdatePassword/Email=John@gmail.com/Token=809a5bc2-5f1b-ce5b0203ff1b

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UpdatePassword(string Email, string Token)
        {
            using (var db = new MyappEntities())
            {

                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated url, try this:

```
http://localhost:53081/Dashboard/UpdatePassword?Email=John@gmail.com&Token=809a5bc2-5f1b-ce5b0203ff1b
```

You can read more about what a querystring is:

https://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Answer (score 1):

Parameter are used as query strings unless you setup routing for them in the pattern you want. Therefore your URL should look like

> http://localhost:53081/Dashboard/UpdatePassword?Email=John@gmail.com&Token=809a5bc2-5f1b-ce5b0203ff1b

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect way to pass the parameters. You need to follow the query string format (notice that @ is encoded):

```
http://localhost:53081/Dashboard/UpdatePassword?Email=John%40gmail.com&Token=809a5bc2-5f1b-ce5b0203ff1b
```

Another option would be

```
http://localhost:53081/Dashboard/UpdatePassword/John%40gmail.com/809a5bc2-5f1b-ce5b0203ff1b
```

but that requires additional setup in your routing config, and frankly looks a bit off.